# Call Login Page on Background in Android

Tags: android

I am working on some app in that app i need to Log in to the page through web services  from background and web services response will come on the UI screen. please give me some guidance on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use the asynctask class provided by android which is use for background operation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for reply . I am using AsyncTask only for posting username and password but how about login ? what operation should be add for login button so that i can show the next page(after login page) on the UI  .

Comment: you can override method onPostExecute(Result) of AsynTask. and call the loginpage.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,My result should be the next page after log in. but how to handle the log in button. because i need to show next url with access token.Access token would not be same for every log in. i will save the access token in the phone memory but how to get the access token without log in. Do you have any idea about this ? please guide me on this.

Comment: you shoul save your accesstoken in sharedpreference and get from it when ever you need....